# How to select related table's related table using prisma?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

I have prisma schema like this:

```
model Permission {
  id    String            @id @default(cuid())
  name  String
  roles RolePermissions[]
}

model Role {
  id          String            @id @default(cuid())
  name        String
  permissions RolePermissions[]
  users       UserRoles[]
}

model User {
  id            String      @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?     @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  roles         UserRoles[]
}

model UserRoles {
  user       User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId     String
  role       Role     @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])
  roleId     String
  assignedAt DateTime @default(now())
  assignedBy String?

  @@id([userId, roleId])
}

model RolePermissions {
  role         Role       @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])
  roleId       String
  permission   Permission @relation(fields: [permissionId], references: [id])
  permissionId String
  assignedAt   DateTime   @default(now())
  assignedBy   String?

  @@id([roleId, permissionId])
}
```

So, each user can have multiple roles and each role can have multiple permissions, which, as you understand, means each user has multiple permissions.

**My goal** is to select user's permisions, based on which roles he assigned to.

Proplem is, what I don't understand how to do it:

I know, I can select user's roles by

```js
 const res  = await prisma.user.findFirst(
        {
            include: {
                roles: true
            }
        }
    )
```

So, it will give me user's roles, but I need to get permissions each of user's roles.

I thought, I can do it like this:

```js
 const res  = await prisma.user.findFirst(
        {
            include: {
                roles: {
                    include: {
                        permissions: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

But this gives me error:

[image]

So, how can I get user's permissions from user's roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says (albeit not very clearly) `permissions` does not exist in the `UserRoles` table. It's in the `Role` table. You need to go 3 levels deep.

```js
const res  = await prisma.user.findFirst(
  {
    include: {
      roles: {
        include: {
          role: {
            include: {
              permissions: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Not sure if my syntax is correct, but you get the point.